# How do I get end of life data for all Ubuntu releases programatically Python

Tags: python

**I previously asked this question and got told the data is in *The package distro-info-data contains a file named /usr/share/distro-info/ubuntu.csv.* However, I do not use Ubuntu/Linux. I am using a Macbook and trying to get this information**

Is there an API/Package that is provided by Ubuntu to get end-of-life date for all past and present releases of Ubuntu - like the data on wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases but via an API/Package ?

Also, I'm already aware about third party websites providing this data, but I would rather get it from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Download the `distro-info-data` package from https://packages.ubuntu.com.

Step 2: The package is simply an .ar archive. Pull the `ubuntu.csv` file out of that archive.

- Some folks find that they need to rename the archive. Change foo.deb to foo.ar

Step 3: Parse the csv file.

Comment: however i would like to automate this so downloading it everytime doesnt sound efficient

Comment: @MonkeyDLuffy downloading a paltry 6kb package twice each year (the `ubuntu.csv` file changes in April and October) does not seem onerous or inefficient. Downloading the package more often would be inefficient.